# jQuery selector problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am stuck in a selector problem in JQuery. I have the following html structure ....

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td rowspan="3"></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td rowspan="3"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td rowspan="4"></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td rowspan="4"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
 </tr>
 ....
</table>
```

I want to select the first td in a tr having the property rowspan. How can I select this using JQuery selectors.

something like $("table > tr > td[rowspan]") selects all the td's having the rowspan property.

Regards

Comment: Does that mean "the first td in a tr if is has a rowspan property" or "the first of the td:s in a tr that has a rowspan property"? I.e. would a td from this row be included: `<tr><td></td><td rowspan="3"></td></tr>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

```
$("table td[rowspan]:first-child")
```

As @kobi said, there is an implicit tbody element that browsers inject. To be very specific, use:

```
$("table > tbody > tr > td[rowspan]:first-child")
```

Comment: You should still answer Guffa's comment in your question. If the answer to that is yes, then my solution will not work. The code example you gave does not contain his case.

Answer (score 4):

`<table>`s have implicit `<tbody>`, that is why your selector isn't working. Try:

```
$("table td[rowspan]")
```

Now, the first `<td>` in each `<tr>` would be:

```
$("table tr").find("td[rowspan]:first")
```

Working example (quite messy, but that's your table): http://jsbin.com/aqere/2

Comment: I want to select the first <td> in every <tr> that has the attribute rowspan. The code snippet you told still selects all the <td>s.

Comment: Even if I throw in the <tbody> tag and add the tag in html, this still doesn't work.

Comment: @Kobi - didn't work in chrome either. I was checking in Chrome that time.

Comment: @ShiVik - interesting. It works for me in chrome, by the way. It seems IE rewrites the `<td>`, I can see it when I use the dom inspector. I'll look into that later...